# Convert list of an entity to an array of ints

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I need to fill an array with 60 values type int, and I have the values inside a DbSet in the database.

Without making a loop, is there a way I can conver this List to a Int[].
The value is in a property called temperature

```
public void SetLineChartData()
{
    //Suppose we have a list of 60 items.
    using (ZigBeeContext db = new ZigBeeContext())
    {
        var lista = (from p in db.Medidas
        select new Medida
        {
            Fecha = p.FechaHora
        }).ToList();
    }

    lineChartData = new int[60];
    lineChartData[0] = RandomNumberGenerator.randomScalingFactor();
    hora[0] = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();

    lineChartData[1] = RandomNumberGenerator.randomScalingFactor();
    hora[1] = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();

    lineChartData[2] = RandomNumberGenerator.randomScalingFactor();
    hora[2] = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();

    lineChartData[3] = RandomNumberGenerator.randomScalingFactor();
    hora[3] = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();

    lineChartData[4] = RandomNumberGenerator.randomScalingFactor();
    hora[4] = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();

    lineChartData[5] = RandomNumberGenerator.randomScalingFactor();
    hora[5] = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();

    lineChartData[6] = RandomNumberGenerator.randomScalingFactor();
    hora[6] = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();

    //colorString = "rgba(" + RandomNumberGenerator.randomColorFactor() + "," + RandomNumberGenerator.randomColorFactor() + "," + RandomNumberGenerator.randomColorFactor() + ",.3)";
}
```

I need to fill an array with 60 values type int, and I have the values inside a DbSet in the database.

Without making a loop, is there a way I can conver this List to a Int[]. The value is in a property called temperature

Comment: With Linq you can do that.

Comment: do you want to bind your `int` List from this `db.Medidas` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "Without making a loop" as many functions will perform loops even if they don't look like it.
If I understand what you are trying to do, then maybe something like this:

```
int[] myArray = lista.Select(x => x.temperature).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

LINQ can provide what you are asking for:

```
var arr = lista.Select(i => i.Fecha).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

With Linq you can do that like this :

```
List<MyObject> lst = new List<MyObject>(); // fake dbSet can be Queryable

int[] toto =   lst.Take(60).Select(item => item.MyInt).ToArray();


private class MyObject
{
    public int MyInt { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use Linq:

```
public void SetLineChartData()
{
    int[] yourIntArray; // your int array
    //Suppose we have a list of 60 items.
    using (ZigBeeContext db = new ZigBeeContext())
    {
        var lista = (from p in db.Medidas
                        select new Medida
                        {
                            Fecha = p.FechaHora,
                        }).ToList();
        // here is how you can do that
        yourIntArray = lista.Select(x => 
                        x.FechaHora //i think that's property that you need to be in int array
                        ).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If FechaHora is not an int already, and you want to cast it, you could do this...

```
int[] lista = db.Medidas.Select(p => p.FechaHora).Cast<int>().ToArray();
```